# How to reinstall Java 6 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: java, android, macos, java-7, java-6

I recently installed Oracle's Java 7 for OS X Mountain Lion (version 10.8.2) on my Mac computer. I was happy with this until I started doing Android development, which is throwing errors at me for using Java 7. Now I want to install Java 6 so I can use it for Android development, but I've looked everywhere for a way to do this and am unable to find any solutions. Is it even possible? What can I do?

I tried downloading [this Java for OS X update](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1421), but when I try to install it I just get this message:

```
A newer version of this package is already installed.
```

Then the installer closes and that's it.

Comment: Have you tried following Oracle's recommendation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mac-faq.html#revert

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, and it seems to uninstall Java 7, but the reinstall step doesn't actually do anything. When I type `java -version`, it still seems to think Java 7 is installed.